# Android room library set field to update database

Tags: android, android-room

I use android room library and I want to update the SQLite database but I am not sure how to set the fields properly. First, I check if the contact name already exists then I can update the details. if it doesn't exist I add a new contact. Adding a new contact is okay but I am not sure how to properly set the email and mobile field to update it.

```html
private ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
  public void saveContact(View view) {
     

 EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        String name = nameField.getText().toString();
        EditText emailField=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        String email = emailField.getText().toString();
        EditText phoneField=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile);
        String mobile = phoneField.getText().toString();

 contactRepository = new ContactRepository(this);
        contactRepository.getAllContacts().observe(this, new Observer<List<Contact>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Contact> updatedContacts) {
                // update the contacts list when the database changes
                adapter.clear();
                adapter.addAll(updatedContacts);
            }
        });

 contactListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactsListView);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contacts);
        contactListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        contactListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


 boolean contactExist = false;
        for(int i=0;i<contacts.size();i++){
            if(contacts.get(i).name.equals(name)){
                contactExist = true;
                contacts.set(1,email);
                contacts.set(2,mobile);
                contactRepository.update(contacts);
                
            }
        }
        if (!contactExist) {

            //contacts.add(new Contact(name, email, mobile));
            contactRepository.insert(new Contact(name,email,mobile));
        }
}
```

```html
@Entity
public class Contact  implements Parcelable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long id;
    public String name;
    public String email;
    public String mobile;
    public Contact(String name, String email, String mobile) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
```

Comment: in dao while inserting write `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)` . This will add if data is not there , If the data is there then it will replace it

Comment: OnConflict strategy applies to UNIQUE, NOT NULL, CHECK, and PRIMARY KEY constraints. Make sure name is any of this constraints.

Comment: I think the email and mobile type needs to be Contact but is seeing Strings. any idea how I could set the type to Contact. Because  it's complaining about the type

Comment: I've added my Contact class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm developing an App who uses Android Room library too. In my case, I've implemented the update logic using setter methods in the class annotated with the `@Entity`. Try something like this:

In your Contact class:

```
public void setContactName(String contactName){
    name = contactName;
}

public void setContactEmail(String contactEmail){
    email = contactEmail;
}

public void setContactMobile(String contactMobile){
    mobile = contactMobile;
}
```

Then, in the Activity you're trying to create a new Contact or update an existing one, do something like this:

```
Contact myEditingContact;

if (!contactExist) {

contactRepository.insert(new Contact(name,email,mobile));

} else {

myEditingContact.setContactName(name);
myEditingContact.setContactEmail(email);
myEditingContact.setContactMobile(mobile);

contactRepository.updateContact(myEditingContact);
}
```

For this `updateContact` method to work correctly, you'll need to declare it in your `Dao`:

```
@Update
void updateContact(Contact... contacts);
```

And in your `Repository`:

```
public void updateContact(Contact contact){
    new updateContactAsyncTask(myContactDao).execute(contact);
}

private static class updateContactAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Contact, Void, Void> {

    private ContactDao mAsyncTaskDao;

    updateContactAsyncTask(ContactDao dao) {
        mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Contact... contacts) {
        mAsyncTaskDao.updateContact(contacts[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Final Note 1: When your user try to edit a Contact, for example, when the user touches one of your ListView itens, the variable `Contact myEditingContact` needs to be initialized. You can do it inside your `OnItemClickListener`, passing to that variable the Contact object corresponding to the clicked item. If you has difficult with this, post your adapter and your OnItemClick, and I will try to help you.

Final Note 2: As I do not know the code of your other Classes, like your Dao, your Repository, etc. it's possible I have mentioned variables or objects from your other classes with wrong names. So, when you try to implement the logic, be aware of it.

I really hope this had helped =)